# std::string is ambiguous, whenever including non-standard libraries like boost

Tags: c++, boost, std, ubuntu-16.04

JSONParser.h

```
#ifndef UTILITY_CLASSES_JSONPARSER_H_
#define UTILITY_CLASSES_JSONPARSER_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>

namespace Parsers {

class JSONParser {
    boost::property_tree::ptree pTree;
public:
    JSONParser();
    virtual ~JSONParser();

    void setJSON(char* JSON);
};

} /* namespace Parsers */

#endif /* UTILITY_CLASSES_JSONPARSER_H_ */
```

JSONParser.cpp

```
/*
 * JSONParser.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: 20-May-2016
 *      Author: arjun
 */

#include "JSONParser.h"

namespace Parsers {

JSONParser::JSONParser() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}

JSONParser::~JSONParser() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}
void JSONParser::setJSON(char* JSON){
    std::string temp;

    pTree.put("foo", "bar");
    pTree.put("foor", "bawr");
    std::ostringstream buf;
    write_json (buf, pTree, false);
}
} /* namespace Parsers */
```

Defined above, are a cpp-header pair I've written for a JSONParser. However, an error is thrown when I try to use std::strings:

> std::string is ambiguous.

It seems this happens whenever I include `boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp`, i.e. whenever I delete the include for it, there is no error.
The same happens when I include something off of `GeographicLib`.
I'm on Ubuntu 16.04, my libraries are in `usr/local/lib`, and includes are in `usr/local/include`

The error is as follows:

> Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   'std::string' is ambiguous '
>   Candidates are:
>   '   JSONParser.cpp  /PSO-PathFinding/Utility Classes    line 14 Semantic Error

Programming on Eclipse, using cdt.

Comment: Once I replaced the unknown `pt2` variable with (wild guess) `pTree`, [it compiles fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/210c7964aba677f3). Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Okay, it doesn't happen with other libraries like tbb. I believe the problem is that boost/property_tree/json_parser uses string within it's own definition.

Comment: show the exact error message too

Comment: you are also missing `#include <sstream>`

Comment: @Quentin, I've edited.
Here's the error message:
'std::string' is ambiguous '
Candidates are:
' JSONParser.cpp /PSO-PathFinding/Utility Classes line 21 Semantic Error

Comment: @M.M, I tried including sstream, changed nothing.

Comment: in the question include the exact and complete error messages with the actual formatting

Comment: also put `#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>` after the standard headers, instead of before

Comment: Did it. Still doesn't work.
Strangely, I can compile it on a different workspace on eclipse, with no problems.

Comment: I'll flag this as resolved. Clearly, this isn't a C++ compiler problem, rather an eclipse one.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved. Not a C++ issue, or boost library issue. Seems to be a problem with the current eclipse workspace I'm working with.